# How to detect input from external device in Python?

Tags: python, windows, io

I have a Wireless Bluetooth headset which comes with a detatchable microphone that I do not use. On it, there is a mute microphone button that I can press to toggle between `muted` and `unmuted`.
The headset in question may be relevant. It is the [HyperX Cloud Alpha Wireless](https://hyperx.com/products/hyperx-cloud-alpha-wireless?variant=42135502422173) and I use it with a Windows 10 PC.

I would like to find a way to capture the button press and remap it to something else. For instance, instead of it toggling `mute` and `unmute` on the headset, it would toggle `play` and `pause` on my current media being played, or I could remap it to some keypress.

Is this possible? If so, what is the best way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know this type of headset, but be aware that sometimes the switch Muted/Unmuted is not connected to your computer. It just stops transmitting data from your mic. On my headset, the sound button is local, i mean that the is the sound of your computer and there is the sound of your headphone.

Comment: @Fredericka I am afraid that this may be the case which is why I linked my headset in case anyone knows whether or not mine has this. If possible I would like to know how to do this regardless of whether or not my specific headset can do this, maybe someone else will stumble upon this question with a similar desire. :)